# Calling a separate executable file in C++?

Tags: php, c++, concurrency

I am currently learning PHP and using `exec()`. I have never done anything similar in C++ and although I assume its not out of the question I cant seem to find anyone talking about it on here, so I thought I'd ask for some guidance in the matter... Is it OS dependant? are there multiple options for this task? How to pass arguments and catch return values? ...

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux systems read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn more about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), `system`, `popen` ....

Comment: And if you are using Windows, [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be what you are look for. BTW, the [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/]) will work on both Linux & Windows, but you won't be able to capture stdout or stderr. (To do that, re-direct stdout & stderr to a temp file and read them back.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for cross-platform solutions, I highly recommend looking at [boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/)